# Why did this Zygon villain drop control over the situation?

Tags: doctor-who

In the end of the last episode S09E08 of *Doctor Who (2005)*,

> Clara's duplicate villain Bonnie threatened that she would kill real Clara if The Doctor doesn't reveal which box would unmask the Zygons across the world. After The Doctor said that it was the blue one and Bonnie opened the box, she turned mad and demanded to bring The Doctor to the Black Archives. And then, The Doctor overpowered Bonnie.

My question is:

> Why didn't Bonnie continue to threaten The Doctor over the phone that the real Clara would die if he doesn't tell which button would unmask the Zygons?

Comment: If it was me (note, I haven't given this a lot of thought - honest) I would want the Doctor there so he could watch as I killed Clara, and then kill him if I didn't get my own way.

Comment: Good question, but I don't think there's a good in-universe answer. Narrative imperative is the best you're going to get :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would think that in the first situation where "Bonnie" is threatening Clara, the choice is purely simple. Two boxes, two buttons, two possible outcomes. "Bonnie" just needs to find the correct one out of two.

When "Bonnie" finally finds out, she opens the boxes to reveal 2 more buttons for each box. Each box has a button labeled "Truth" and another labeled "Consequences". The first thing to consider is that there are now four buttons with four (inferred) possible outcomes. "Bonnie" only knew of two possible outcomes at this point. The second thing to consider is that the terrorist group was named "Truth or Consequences". If this were me, I would consider this to be a type of mocking.

With the doubled complexity of the situation combined with The Doctors foreknowledge of the "Truth or Consequences" name, "Bonnie" was probably a little upset. Which she then had The Doctor brought to her to get the answers from him herself.

Comment: It's not entirely made clear, but it was implied that it had already happen other 15 times before, and The Doctor erased their memories each time. Only this last time, he spared Bonnie's memory because -apparently- she finally got the point. Again, not entirely clear. Maybe he referred to 15 different "rebel" Zygons (which has made me think of a question I might make soon)

Comment: @tilley31 or they were in that room 15 times and every time they failed until they finally got the point, as in it was 15 times at that moment and this was the first time they had all been their but had been erased 15 times